Passing instance of a scoped service into a singleton
I have a scoped service ScopedA, that I inject via DI into another scoped service ScopedB.
I also inject a third Singleton service Singleton1:
public class ScopedB
{
    ScopedA _scopedA;
    Singleton1 _singleton1;

    public ServiceB(ScopedA scopedA, Singleton1 singleton1)
    {
       _scopedA = scopedA;
       _singleton1 = singletonA;
    }
    
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
       await _singleton1.PerformALongerOperationWichNeedsServiceAAsync(_scopedA);
    }   
}

Singleton1 exists only one time during the whole lifetime of the process, whereas ScopedA and ScopedB exist only during a HTTP Request (scoped).
What will happen if I pass the instance _scopedA to a function of the _singleton1 that is processing something in the background for a longer time?
Lets say my request is over already and DoSomethingAsync already finished, but the singleton service is still doing something with _scopedA.
Will ASP.NET destroy my scoped instance of ScopedA inside the function call, so that something will fail?   Or can something like this be done without problems?
I know that it would not be recommended to inject _scopedA directly into _singleton1, because this would violate the scope.
Is my example also violating the scope?
In case this is relevant, I am using ASP.NET 6 (as an API) using the built-in DI Container (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection).

You are awaiting the method. If _serviceS stores the _serviceA reference to use even after the method call yes you presumably have a bigger issue. IS ServiceA even disposable?

@DavidMason It's recommended to use the IServiceProvider in your singleton class by injecting it into the singleton, to create the scoped service.  how-to-use-scoped-dependency-injection-in-singleton or as MSDN recommends, use the IServiceScopeFactory - Use scoped services within a BackgroundService


Will ASP.NET destroy my scoped instance of ScopedA inside the function call, so that something will fail?

The singleton will be able to use ScopedA unless that class -or one of its dependencies- implement IDisposable (or IAsyncDisposable).
The DI Container will unreference ScopedA when the scope ends. But since Singleton1 still holds a reference to it, ScopedA will not be garbage collected.
But in case ScopedA -or one of its dependencies- gets disposed, they will be disposed of (or they can be) before Singleton1 is done with its background operation. This can cause a ObjectDisposedException will be thrown when Singleton1 tries to access ScopedA.
Although this all might function when the object graph for ScopedA does not contain any disposable objects, there are still many catches to this, such as:

While ScopedA might not implement IDisposable, it's typically hard to get track of whether this holds for all its dependencies. So while Singleton1 might be able to successfully  call ScopedA today, adding IDisposable later on to another class in the system might cause the application to break.
The fact that ScopedA is registered ad Scoped is an indication that it is not thread safe. Passing it on to Singleton1, which accesses it on a different thread (in parallel to the main operation), might not be a good idea.
This is a design that will confuse other developers, as it is common knowledge that Scoped instances should not be used in parallel across threads. When I would stumble upon such code, I will likely stop what I'm working on, and start to investigate this code. I will start to talk with the other developers. This means that, even if you figured out that this is actually a correct working solution, other developers will easily spend (waste) time on this code.

Instead of passing on a scoped dependency to a singleton that keeps the dependency alive after its scope ended, let the singleton resolve its own scoped dependency from its own scope that lives for the duration of the background operation.

Good points. Especially the emphasis on "it might work now but may break anytime in a living changing product in this uncommon unexpected setup".

Perfect, thanks. I did not implement it like this, because I had a bad feeling already. Now I have a good "reason" for this feeling ;)

This means that "Dispose()" is always called by the framework when the scope is "over"?

Well, "always" is a strong word. There are cases were it doesn't such as when registering an instance using AddSingleton(T instance) extension method. But generally, yes.

But also understand that when transients are resolved from the root scope, they only get disposed of when the root scope (i.e. the container itself) is disposed of. In other words disposable transients will keep being referenced, so you should prevent ever resolving from the root scope itself, as this can lead to memory leaks.
